# debugging a strange error when new is called

Tags: visual-c++

I have a program that when run compiled with Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Express crashes on the line

```
comparison_vectors = new vec_element[(rbfnetparams->comparison_vector_length)+1];
```

with the error Unhandled exception at 0x7c93426d in myprog.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000

`rbfnetparams->comparison_vector_length` evaluates to 4 (should do and checked in the debugger), and the thing still crashes here when I change the line as a test to:

```
comparison_vectors = new vec_element[5];
```

`vec_element` is a structure with several ints, doubles and a few bools, but no methods or constructor.  The thing runs if I replace new with malloc, but then crashes on another new elsewhere. It does not crash every time this line is run, only sometimes, but seems to do so after the same number of iterations of this line each time. Memory usage is only 10MB at this point in the program.

This gets stranger as the same program DOES compile and run under gcc on Solaris, which usually shows up far more errors than Windows does.

Any help would be appreciated, as I am at a loss as to how to debug this one.

Comment: It sounds like a heap corruption issue to me. Have you tried running the program under valgrind?

Comment: ...or run the Debug version under VS itself, that usually shows up heap problems quickly.  Problem is likely not on this line but earlier.

Comment: If he's on Windows, this won't work - no Valgrind port for Windows. That said, if his code can be compiled on a *nix system he can check, but if he's using Windows conventions (which is highly likely if cross-platform is not in mind) then he will be out of luck with that.

Comment: Usually stuff like this I have to debug in assembly.

Comment: Thanks for the valgrind idea. since the thing was cross platform anyway with a solaris version working, got the thing to compile under linux, and quite a bit earlier in the program the names of 2 arrays had got muddled up, so an illegal write was taking place which valgrind found instantly, and the Visual Studio debugger did not detect. I'd accept if it was posted as an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 1):

`Access violation reading location 0x00000000` means "you dereferenced a `NULL` pointer."  It looks like once in a while `rbfnetparams` is `NULL` when you reach this line, and thus you get the error.

I can't explain why `comparison_vectors = new vec_element[5];` crashes.  Is it the same error message?

Check if `rbfnetparams` is `NULL` before the line, and see if it gets hit (or add a conditional break point).  Then decide if the fact that `rbfnetparams` is `NULL` is a symptom of a bigger bug somewhere else.

Dereferencing a `NULL` pointer is undefined.  It's possible that the Solaris compiler does an optimization that masks the bug.  [That's allowed by the Standard](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_21.html) (read the whole series referenced from that post).

Comment: Thhe fact that new crashes when allocating 5 is proof you're barking up the wrong tree.  He has heap corruption.

Comment: @MooingDuck, normally I'd agree with you.  But "Access violation reading location 0x00000000" always means "`NULL` pointer dereference."  It doesn't have another meaning.  It may be that the `NULL` is an internal variable used by the memory allocation routines but I doubt it.  I've seen enough cases on SO that an "identical error" turned out to not be identical, or turned out to be an incorrect report, or in some way turned out to be a red herring that I've decided to overlook that part of the report, and mention that I'm overlooking it.

Comment: @MaxLybbery: I guess I wasn't clear, he is definitely dereferencing a `NULL` pointer, but the _cause_ of the `NULL` pointer is heap corruption.  The `NULL` pointer is merely a coincidental side-effect.